# Evaluate the contour integral $\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n}dz \hspace{10mm} n=1,2,3,\cdots .$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\gamma(z_0,R)$ denote the circular contour $z_0+Re^{it}$ for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$. Evaluate 
$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n}dz \hspace{10mm} n=1,2,3,\cdots .$$

Using Cauchy's formula:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n}dz & = 2\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2z^n}dz \\
& = 2\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{\cosh}{z^n} \\
& = \frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\cosh(z) \right).
\end{align*}
Then evaluating at $0$ gives
$$\frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}\sinh(0)\hspace{10mm} \text{if $n$ is even}$$
and
$$\frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}\cosh(0) \hspace{10mm} \text{if $n$ is odd}.$$

Please let me know if I have made a mistake.

Comment: In the last line of "Using Cauchy's formula:", you have dropped a factor $2$. You got that back at "Then evaluating". In the first line of that, you have mistyped $e^z - e^{-z}$ on the right hand side. Further simplification: what are $\sinh 0$ resp $\cosh 0$?

Comment: I've attempted to correct the factor error. And $\sinh(0)=0$ and $\cosh(0)=1$, so would that mean the answer is $0$ when $n$ is even and $\frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}$ when $n$ is odd?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So there's the $e^z - e^{-z}$ typo remaining before you have it entirely correct.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see the typo and I have amended it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use residue theorem alternatively: Laurant series representation of $\dfrac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n}$ is
$$
\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n}=\frac{2}{z^n}\cosh z = \frac{2}{z^n}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\frac{z^6}{6!}+\cdots\right)
$$
If $n$ is even, then residue of $f$, that is, the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $0$, and if $n$ is odd, then the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $2/(n-1)!$. Since $f$ has a pole only at $z=0$ and it is inside $\gamma(0,1)$, the residue theorem says that
$$
\int_{\gamma(0,1)}\frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{z^n} dz =2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f;0)
$$
and get the conclusion that is same with your attempt.